# stop updating column value when status is settled for similar lead id using PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a following mysql table, where multiple user  has accepted a lead (lead_id). here i want to stop updating table column 'Value' when 'status' is 'settled

```php
<?php
    
$sql = "SELECT `status`,`email_id` FROM `deal_request` WHERE `client_id` = '$client_id'";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $status = $row['status'];
             
        if ($status == 'pending') {
            $sql = "UPDATE `deal_request` SET `status`='settled',`share_userdetails` ='2' WHERE `client_id`='$client_id' AND `dealer_id`='$dealer_id'";
            $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            if ($query == true) {
                echo " <script>
                                alert(\"You Have Successfully Released The Lead\");
                                window.location.replace(\"LeadDetails.php?client_id=$client_id&&dealer_id=$dealer_id\");
                                </script>";
            }
        } else {
            echo 'you can not change';
            echo " <script>
                            alert(\"You cannot select this dealer, another dealer has been selected aleady!\");
                            window.location.replace(\"LeadDetails.php?client_id=$client_id&&dealer_id=$dealer_id\");
                        </script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You probably just need to add `WHERE status !='settled'`..

Comment: @FanoFN I think he means when some *other* row has status = settled, he doesn't want to allow a user to accept the lead.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, or is @FanoFN correct?

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: The columns in your code are not the same as the columns in the table.

Comment: DON'T PUT CODE IN COMMENTS!!!!

Comment: table is big, so i tried to write that all in simple form so i change it

Comment: You did an edit on your question before right @JasonPerry ? Just [edit your question again](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73821790/edit) and put all your codes in there. Then you delete the comments with codes.

Comment: @FanoFN I think he means when some other row has status = settled, he doesn't want to allow a user to accept the lead.                          Yes, exactly.

Comment: what is the question, what have you tried, and what is the result/problem? we can't help if as far as we know this code you pasted is working fine. give a detailed account.

Comment: I don't think this is a MySQL issue, right?

Comment: when status='settled' in any of the client_id, i don't want to allow a user to accept the lead. i have posted code, i tried it, but i could'nt figure out.

Comment: There's no `lead_id` in the table, do you mean `client_id`?

Comment: yes, there's no sql error. it is working. only logical part not working as i want. i dont want user to click on button to release lead when the lead is realsed to somebody else already.

Comment: lead_id is client_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the count of rows with `status = 'settled'`. If it's more than 0, don't allow accepting the lead.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM deal_request 
    WHERE client_id = ? AND status = 'settled'");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $client_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row['count'] == 0) {
    // code to accept the lead
} else {
    // code to report that the lead cannot be accepted
}
```